# How to serialize object fields with NLog?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, config, nlog

Im testing out the new [structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) but do not really get it right.

I have this in my nlog.config :

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message}</layout>
</target>

<logger name="CommunicationLogger" minlevel="Info" writeto="f"></logger>
```

My log code looks like this :

```
public void LogCommunication(string operation, List<object> args)
    {
        var parameters = new List<object>();

        var text = "Operation:{Operation} ";
        parameters.Add(operation);

        text += "PersonId:{PersonId} ";
        parameters.Add(SharedContext.GetMyUserContext().CurrentPersonId);

        text += "ClientMachineName:{ComputerName} ";
        parameters.Add(SharedContext.GetMyUserContext().ClientMachineName);

        text += "Servername:{MachineName} ";
        parameters.Add(Environment.MachineName);

        if (args != null)
        {
            foreach(var param in args)
            {
                text += "Param:{@Parameters} ";
                parameters.Add(param);
            }

        }

        _log.LogCommunication(text, parameters.ToArray());
    }

public void LogCommunication(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            _comLogger.Log(LogLevel.Info, message, args);
        }
```

The output looks something like this :

> { "Operation": "OperationName", "PersonId": 1, "ComputerName":
>   "MyComputername", "MachineName": "MyMachinename", "Parameters":
>   {"LocationKeyList":[], "MyObjectIdList":[], "RolList":[]} }

I would like the Parameters to also get serialize instead of just showint [] so I can see all the parameters of the service operation. The parameter is a complex type with dataContract(WCF).

Is there a simple way to get the parameters to work with structural data.

Retagards

**Update1**

nlog.config

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10">
    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
  </layout>
</target>
```

Code to setup data

```
var parameters = new List<object>();

            var text = "{TimeStamp} - ";
            parameters.Add(DateTime.Now);

            text += "Duration:{Duration} ";
            parameters.Add(Timestamp);

            text += "Operation:{Operation} ";
            parameters.Add(operation);

            text += "PersonId:{PersonId} ";
            parameters.Add(SharedContext.GetMyUserContext().CurrentPersonId);

            text += "ClientMachineName:{ComputerName} ";
            parameters.Add(SharedContext.GetMyUserContext().ClientMachineName);

            text += "Servername:{MachineName} ";
            parameters.Add(Environment.MachineName);

            if (args != null && args.Count() > 0)
            {
                text += "Param:{@Parameters} ";
                parameters.Add(args);
            }

            _log.LogCommunication(text, parameters.ToArray());
```

result :

> ientMachineName:\"MyComputer\" Servername:\"MyComputer\"
>   Param:[\"MyApp.ServiceContracts.GetEntityViewRequest\"] ",
>   "TimeStamp": "2020-04-08T23:30:59.7725147Z", "Duration":
>   "00:00:00.0009930", "Operation": "GetReferenceData", "PersonId": 1,
>   "ComputerName": "SE-MyCom", "MachineName": "SE-MyCom",
>   "Parameters": ["MyApp.ServiceContracts.GetEntityViewRequest"] }
>
> { "time": "2020-04-09 01:31:00.3637", "level": "Info", "message":
>   "2020-04-09 01:31:00 - Duration:00:00:00.5594936
>   Operation:\"GetExternaAnrop\" PersonId:1
>   ClientMachineName:\"MyComputer\" Servername:\"MyComputer\"
>   Param:[{\"PlaceringKeyList\":[], \"ArbetsstalleIdList\":[],
>   \"RollList\":[]}] ", "TimeStamp": "2020-04-08T23:31:00.363752Z",
>   "Duration": "00:00:00.5594936", "Operation": "GetExternaAnrop",
>   "PersonId": 1, "ComputerName": "SE-MyCom", "MachineName":
>   "SE-MyCom", "Parameters": [{"PlaceringKeyList":[],
>   "ArbetsstalleIdList":[], "RollList":[]}] }

**Update2**

I have a service method that looks like this :

```
GetEntityViewResponse GetReferenceData(GetEntityViewRequest request);
```

The request class looks like this :

```
[DataContract]
    public class GetEntityViewRequest
    {
        public GetEntityViewRequest(params EntityViewKey[] Keys)
        {
            EntityViewKeys.AddRange(Keys);
        }
        public GetEntityViewRequest(params int[] EgnaKodtyper)
        {
            MyList.AddRange(EgnaKodtyper);
        }
        public GetEntityViewRequest()
        {

        }
        [DataMember]
        public List<EntityViewKey> EntityViewKeys = new List<EntityViewKey>();
        [DataMember]
        public List<int> MyList= new List<int>();
    }
```

When running the code(sending the request) I can see in my messageInspector on the serviceside that I got data. The EntityViewKeys have a enum set.

The NLog output looks like this :

> { "time": "2020-04-12 19:27:55.6690", "level": "Info", "message":
>   "2020-04-12 19:27:55 - Duration:00:00:00.0034730
>   Operation:\"GetReferenceData\" PersonId:1
>   ClientMachineName:\"MyComputer\" Servername:\"MyComputer\"
>   Param:[\"Orbit.ServiceContracts.GetEntityViewRequest\"] ",
>   "TimeStamp": "2020-04-12T17:27:55.6690745Z", "Duration":
>   "00:00:00.0034730", "Operation": "GetReferenceData", "PersonId": 1,
>   "ComputerName": "SE-MyCom", "MachineName": "SE-MyCom",
>   "Parameters": ["Orbit.ServiceContracts.GetEntityViewRequest"] }

So even if the class is not complex it is still not printing the content in NLog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an important parameter for JsonLayout called `MaxRecursionLimit` (Default = 0 until NLog v5 arrives):

https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout

So you can do this:

```
<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="10">
              <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
              <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
              <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
</layout>
```

Maybe you want to change your parameters into this:

```
if (args != null)
{
    text += "Params:{@Parameters} ";
    parameters.Add(args);
}
```

NLog will by default not serialize object-fields, but only object-properties. If fields are a must, then you can setup setup custom reflection with NLog 4.7:

```
LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<GetEntityViewResponse>(obj => new {
      EntityViewKeys = obj.EntityViewKeys,
      MyList = obj.MyList,
   })
);
```

Or if you are a lazy person:

```
LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<GetEntityViewRequest>(obj => 
       return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(obj) // Lazy and slow
   )
);
```

Comment: Tried this but it does not make any difference : <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="10">${level}|${logger}|${message}</layout>

Comment: @Banshee Any reason why you decide not to perform carbon-copy of my suggestion? (Remove `${level}|${logger}|${message}`)

Comment: @Banshee Also make sure that your updated `NLog.config` is being deployed when doing the test-run.

Comment: @Banshee Have updated my answer with a suggestion for how to pass in your additional `args`. Your original code reused the same parameter-name for all args-elements.

Comment: @Banshee Think you have to show what object-types you are hiding in that bag called `args`. Each object in `args` has a single property, and the type of the property is an array that contains no elements. But it feels like you see them having more content, but I'm not psychic.

Comment: pleas, check Update 2.

Comment: @Banshee NLog only serializes object-properties by default (when having proper getter). It ignores object-fields. It is recommended to change your objects to have properties. You have the option to customize object reflection in NLog 4.7

Comment: Thanks, it woked. This means however that I got a big job before me to remake all fields and detfaults to set/get. I will look at the customization of objects in NLog and see if that could be a solution.

Comment: @Banshee You can tell NLog to perform custom reflection of your own objects. I have added some examples to the answer of how to do this.