# How to use NLog to log unspecified objects to file maintaining ELK Stack compatibility?

Tags: c#, logging, elastic-stack, nlog

I have struggle for weeks to get NLog to log my communication data including unspecific(DataContracts) parameters to file in a format that are ELK-stack compatible. It need to be configured in runtime and its preferred if the output parameters can be limited like MAX chars or depth.

NLog have a built-in JSON serializer but it will only read properties without defaults, fields will be ignored as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103712/how-to-serialize-object-fields-with-nlog). It would be a big job to adapt my data model and I do not really think its the right way to go, NLog should not affect how the data model should look like.

There is a couple of ways to add a [custom JSON serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281449/set-valueformatter-for-specific-nlog-instance)  :

1. I could use SetupSerialization on each class(Datacontract) like this :

   ```
   LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
      s.RegisterObjectTransformation<GetEntityViewRequest>(obj => 
          return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(obj)
      )
   );
   ```

Because I want to log all communication data the entire data model will have to be registered, its huge job and not effective.

2. I could use a custom IValueFormatter but it can´t be added to just my communication NLog instance, it have to be added in globally to all loggers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281449/set-valueformatter-for-specific-nlog-instance) :

   ```
   NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.ValueFormatter = new NLogValueFormatter();
   ```

So the `IValueFormatter` needs to filter so it is only manipulate data from the communication logger. I probably need to wrap my data in a class with a flag that tells `IValueFormatter` where the data come from, It do however not feel like a optimal solution.

There are also problems to actually get NLog to put out the data that the `ValueFormatter` filter as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804131/nlog-ivalueformatter-do-not-output-any-data). The `ValueFormatter` do still run but its the regular NLog JSON data that will end up in the file.

What I need from NLog is this :

- Transform all communication data including parameters from object to string formatted so ELK stack read it.
- Serialization depth or string MAX length on parameters to avoid data overflow
- Configurable from NLog.config in runtime(as NLog is)
- Affect only a specific NLogger instance

My data come in through a IParameterInspector, it is compiled into a special CallInformation class that also holds the parameters(type object). The parameters can be vary complex with several layers. The entire CallInforamtion object is sent to NLog like this :

```
_comLogger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "ComLogger : {@callInfo}", callInfo);
```

The Nlog.config looks like this right now :

```xml
<logger name="CommunicationLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeto="communicationFileLog"></logger>
<target xsi:type="File"
            name="communicationFileLog"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            maxArchiveDays="5"
            maxArchiveFiles="10">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="1">
      </layout>
</target>
```

What am I missing? Is there another log library that might support my needs better?

Comment: Why are you logging to file instead of sending the logs to ES directly using something like https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch. If you have additional properties and need to do some re-structuring/transformation you could also send the logs to Logstash and let it do all of this...

Comment: Im thinking that file is a great buffer for this kind of logging? And we might be able to do less but bigger log transfers. But thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it :)

Comment: Would probably create a custom NLog Layout called NewtonsoftLayout, that allows you to configure how the NewtonSoft JsonSerializer should operate. Inspiration can be found at https://github.com/farzadpanahi/NLog.GelfLayout/tree/master/src/NLog.Layouts.GelfLayout

Comment: Why is the question tagged with serilog?

Comment: @Michael, now removed, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the suggestion of Rolf is the best - create a layout that will use JSON.NET. That one could do all fancy tricks, like serializing fields and handling `[JsonIgnore]`.

A basic version will look like this:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Layouts;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Render all properties to Json with JSON.NET, also include message and exception
    /// </summary>
    [Layout("JsonNetLayout")]
    [ThreadAgnostic] // different thread, same result
    [ThreadSafe]
    public class JsonNetLayout : Layout
    {
        public Formatting Formatting { get; set; } = Formatting.Indented; // This option could be set from the XML config

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override string GetFormattedMessage(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var allProperties = logEvent.Properties ?? new Dictionary<object, object>();
            allProperties["message"] = logEvent.FormattedMessage;
            if (logEvent.Exception != null)
            {
                allProperties["exception"] = logEvent.Exception.ToString(); //toString to prevent too much data properties
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allProperties, Formatting);
        }
    }
}
```

and [register the layout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component), I will use:

```
Layout.Register<JsonNetLayout>("JsonNetLayout"); // namespace NLog.Layouts
```

The needed config:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File"
            name="communicationFileLog"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            maxArchiveDays="5"
            maxArchiveFiles="10">
    <layout xsi:type="JsonNetLayout" />
</target>
```

#### Example

When logging this object:

```
public class ObjectWithFieldsAndJsonStuff
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string _myField = "value1";

    [JsonProperty("newname")]
    public string FieldWithName { get; set; } = "value2";

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string IgnoreMe { get; set; } = "value3";
}
```

And this logger call:

```
logger
    .WithProperty("prop1", "value1")
    .WithProperty("prop2", objectWithFieldsAndJsonStuff)
    .Info("Hi");
```

This will result in:

```
{
  "prop1": "value1",
  "prop2": {
    "_myField": "value1",
    "newname": "value2"
  },
  "message": "Hi"
}
```

#### Unit test

All this above in an unit test - using xUnit

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void JsonNetLayoutTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            Layout.Register<JsonNetLayout>("JsonNetLayout");

            var xmlConfig = @"
<nlog xmlns=""http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd""
      xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
      throwExceptions=""true"">

  <targets>
        <target xsi:type=""Memory"" name=""target1"" >
            <layout xsi:type=""JsonNetLayout"" />
        </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name=""*"" minlevel=""Trace"" writeTo=""target1"" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
";

            LogManager.Configuration = XmlLoggingConfiguration.CreateFromXmlString(xmlConfig);

            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("logger1");

            var memoryTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<MemoryTarget>("target1");

            // Act
            var objectWithFieldsAndJsonStuff = new ObjectWithFieldsAndJsonStuff();
            logger
                .WithProperty("prop1", "value1")
                .WithProperty("prop2", objectWithFieldsAndJsonStuff)
                .Info("Hi");

            // Assert
            var actual = memoryTarget.Logs.Single();
            var expected =
@"{
  ""prop1"": ""value1"",
  ""prop2"": {
    ""_myField"": ""value1"",
    ""newname"": ""value2""
  },
  ""message"": ""Hi""
}";
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
```

Comment: Thankls, this solved my problem! I hade to change to a DataContractJSONSerializer but thats okay :)